# error: endorser client failed to connect in tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running into an error while going through the "writing your first application" tutorial at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.1/write_first_app.html

Upon executing the command "./startFabric.sh javascript" I get this error:

Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:7051: connect: connection refused"

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel'  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Error !!! Create channel failed

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you run this using -s couchdb?

Answer (score 0):

This situation is happened because you called a gRPC to peer server but your call failed to hit the server. This situation may happen for many reasons, but for most of the cases the situation is happened due to server down(peer server exit or down due to misconfiguration) or for wrong certificate or your call failed to hit the server due to misconfiguration.